# Cache webservices by argument passing to the funciton

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching, optimization, webmethod

I wonder how can I cache webservice returned data by its passed argument?

For example:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string FunctionThatReturnsSomething(int param1){
   ... does something
return strResult;

}
```

What I want is that the returned the webservice returned data will be cached, but according to the parameter value (inr param1). So if, for example, the webservice function gets a value of '1', it will cache the results for that. If the functions gets '2' integer for the param1, it will cache another result.

note: the webmethod/webservice is being called via Ajax call using POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET handily provides the [Application Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) just for this sort of thing.

In it's simplest form, you can just add data to the cache like this:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache["Key"] = "Value";
```

So you could cache the data that you want to return easily:

```
string cacheKey = "FunctionThatReturnsSomething_" + param1.ToString();

if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] == null)
{
    string myData = GetDataToReturn(param1);

    HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] = myData; 
}

return (string)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
```

It also allows you to specify a [CacheDependancy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). So for example if your data was based on a local file, you can have the cache automatically cleared if that file is updated.

You can also have data that you enter into the cache removed after a certain time, for example if it hasn't been used for 10 minutes:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, myData, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));
```

Or at an absolute time, such as 10 minutes after you add it:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, myData, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), 
System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: I think that the Cache attribute above the web method does take the parameter into consideration, but I need to be 100% sure. I prefer the attribute because it is simple to use.

Comment: Haha, yes of course! I completely forgot that WebMethods could also use Output Caching, much like User Controls etc. It's worth putting that in a separate answer. You could also refer to [HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) if you ever need to programmatically invalidate the cache.